# Correct use of the NHibernate Unit Of Work pattern and Ninject

Tags: nhibernate, session, transactions, ninject, unit-of-work

I have the following implementation and would like some feedback as to whether it makes correct use of NHibernate for sessions and transactions.

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ISession CurrentSession { get; }
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        CurrentSession = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        _transaction = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public ISession CurrentSession { get; private set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CurrentSession.Close();
        CurrentSession = null;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction.IsActive) _transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Ninject binding

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InTransientScope();
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<NHibernateSessionFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InTransientScope();
```

Here is an example of the usage:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    public Repository(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void Add(IObj obj)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_sessionFactory))
        {
            unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Save(obj);
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }         
    }
}
```

In my previous implementation I would inject IUnitOfWork into my repository constructor like so

```
public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {...
```

But the Dispose() method would not execute causing a subsequent call to throw this exception: "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'AdoTransaction'."

Comment: Not sure what your final decision was BUT don't do it! :) Seriously, NHibernate already adds a great deal of abstraction and a UoW pattern. Just use NHibernate straight out of the box and keep your code simple. Do you really want even more abstraction to debug?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First observation: your repository should not commit the unit of work. This defeats the whole point of the unit of work pattern. By immediately saving your changes inside the repository, you're "micro managing" the NHibernate Session.

The unit of work should be referenced higher up the stack, in your application/service layer. This allows you to have application code that performs several actions, potentially on different repositories, and still at the end commit everything at once.

The UnitOfWork class itself looks Ok, though you should ask yourself if you really need it. In NHibernate, the ISession IS your unit of work. Your UnitOfWork class does not seem to add a lot of value (especially since you're exposing the CurrentSession property anyway)

But you do need to think about it's lifetime. I think you have it wrong on this point. Session lifetime management depends on the type of application you're developing: in a web app, you typically want to have a unit of work per request (you might want to google on 'nhibernate session per request'). In a desktop app it's slightly more complicated, you will most of the time want a 'session per screen' or 'conversation per business transaction'.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jeroenh. Our application only needs to perform simple crud operations and doesn't need to perform several actions and commit everything at once.

Reason why I choose not to work directly against ISession is because I wanted UnitOfWork to abstract away opening sessions, beginning a transation and closing a session.

Comment: The benefit of IUnitOfWork is reduced coupling to ORM.  Or at least that's the only benefit I can think of :)

Comment: @Ryan Barett but what's the use of that? http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/30/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal.aspx

Comment: another round fired in the eternal fight between pragmatism and idealism, and I'm leaning more towards ayende's opinion now..

Comment: I dislike the "absolutism" with which Ayende expresses some of his opinions, this one included. Whether or not it adds value to abstract away the ORM depends on the overall complexity of the application. If your application does no more than simple CRUD, then it really adds only needless complexity. However, if you are doing full blown DDD (AND your project's complexity actually warrants DDD), then abstracting the ORM away behind Repositories, UoW etc probably DOES add value. Recommended reading:   
"Patterns, Principles, and Practices of Domain-Driven Design" (Millet & Tune).

Answer (score 8):

I have a mostly CRUD type of application, and I implemented the Unit Of Work with Repository pattern, but couldn't really get away from the Session/Transaction split.  Sessions and Transactions need different lifetimes.  In the desktop world, a Session is usually "per-screen" and a Transaction is "per-user-action".

More information in this [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx).

So what I ended up with was:

- `IUnitOfWork` -> Wraps session, implements `IDisposable`
- `IAtomicUnitOfWork` -> Wraps transaction, implements `IDisposable`
- `IRepository` -> Provides Get, Save, Delete and query access

I made it so that you need an `IUnitOfWork` to build an `IAtomicUnitOfWork` and you need an `IAtomicUnitOfWork` to build an `IRepository`, so that enforces proper transaction management.  That's really all I gained by implementing my own interfaces.

As jeroenh said, you are almost just as well to use `ISession` and `ITransaction` but in the end I felt a little better writing all my code against an interface that I defined.

Comment: Nice idea sending the IUoW to the IRepository.  As far as the conceptual split: IUoW is, by definition, a transaction.  The concept of a session is a little different the abstraction over it deserves a different name (I'd call it IDatabaseGenericSession)..

Comment: @Ryan Barrett: Yeah, I think a better name for the session wrapper would be some form of "context".  I think ObjectContext is already taken in .NET though, isn't it?  Maybe EntityContext?

Answer (score 4):

An important part of the answer lies in what you want your transaction sizes to be. Right now (as jeroenh has indicated) the transaction is per method invocation on your repository. This is very small and probably not needed. I created an ASP.MVC application and it uses a transaction size that included everything from a single http request. This could be multiple database reads/updates. I am using the same unit of work and Ninject for IOC. Take a look, maybe something will help with your issues:

http://bobcravens.com/2010/06/the-repository-pattern-with-linq-to-fluent-nhibernate-and-mysql/

http://bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://bobcravens.com/2010/09/the-repository-pattern-part-2/

http://bobcravens.com/2010/11/using-ninject-to-manage-critical-resources/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: Thanks for the resources Bob. Even though my application is not an MVC app, the ideas are the same.

Comment: Hi Bob, unfortunately your blog have it's url changed from blog.bobcravens.com to just bobcravens.com. Therefore a lot is broken, as link to images for instance. Hope you could be able to fix it.