# Variety of NHibernate errors relating to transactions during spidering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, ninject

We have an ASP.Net 4 / MVC 3 hybrid web application which uses NInject 3 and (Fluent) NHibernate 3.2. DB is SQL Server 2008 R2.  Server is 6-core 28 GB Windows 2008 64-bit server.

Our customer has recently started testing the site using a spidering tool. As soon as the site experiences the load produced by the spider, our log starts to fill up with exceptions.

We see a variety of errors from NHibernate, including some of the following:

- NHibernate.TransactionException: Commit failed with SQL exception ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction.
- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:410000050f.  The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted by another session.
- System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.GetServerTransactionLevel()....
- NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query:exec [Stats.InsertListingStatsList]     @ListingStats =:ListingStats[SQL: exec [Stats.InsertListingStatsList]     @ListingStats =@p0] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor.

to give just four examples.  All have a similar flavour - they all seem to relate to the management of transactions by ADO.Net as the substrate of NHibernate.

Now, some details of our NH implementation:

- SessionFactory is static;
- SessionFactory uses AdoNetTransactionFactory;
- ISession is in request scope, and stored in the HttpContext.Items collection;
- Repositories are also in request scope;
- We are now using config.CurrentSessionContext();
- Each call to our generic repository uses a transaction

Here are two methods from our repository.

```
public T GetById<T>(int id)
{
    using (var t = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var entity = Session.Get<T>(id);
        t.Commit();
        return entity;
    }
}

public void Add<T>(T entity)
{
    using (var t = Session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        Session.Save(entity);
        t.Commit();
    }
}
```

My question is simple: what is going wrong? What is causing these apparent conflicts between transactions, or between the various data-related operations that our domain instigates as it de/hydrates our domain?

UPDATE: here is our full configuration:

```
public FluentConfiguration BuildConfiguration(string connectionString)
{
    var sqlConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString).AdoNetBatchSize(30);

     var config = Fluently.Configure().Database(sqlConfig);

     var entityMapping = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<User>(new AutomappingConfiguration())
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<UserMappingOverride>()
            .AddMappingsFromAssemblyOf<TableNamingConvention>()
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<TableNamingConvention>();

        var cqrsMapping = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<AdvertView>(new QueryAutomappingConfiguration())
            .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AdvertViewMappingOverride>();

        config.Mappings(c => c.AutoMappings.Add(entityMapping));
        config.Mappings(c => c.AutoMappings.Add(cqrsMapping));

        config.Mappings(c => c.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AdvertView>());

        config.ExposeConfiguration(c => c.SetProperty(Environment.TransactionStrategy, typeof(AdoNetTransactionFactory).FullName));

        config.CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>();

        return config;
    }
```

More code for you guys and gals.  Here is the relevant section of our IoC Container configuration.

```
var domainEntityBootstrapper = new DomainEntitySessionBootStrapper("Domain", "NHibernate.ISession.Domain", _enableLucine, HttpContextItemsProvider);
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(domainEntityBootstrapper.CreateSessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named(domainEntityBootstrapper.Name);
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(domainEntityBootstrapper.GetSession).InRequestScope();

var queryBootstrapper = new QueryEntitySessionBootStrapper("Query", "NHibernate.ISession.Query", HttpContextItemsProvider);
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(queryBootstrapper.CreateSessionFactory).InSingletonScope().Named(queryBootstrapper.Name);
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(queryBootstrapper.GetSession).WhenInjectedInto(typeof (QueryExecutor)).InRequestScope();
```

and here is the code from the GetSession() method of the base class for these SessionBootstrappers (please note that the CreateSessionFactory method calls the BuildConfiguration method above and then calls BuildSessionFactory()).

```
public virtual ISession GetSession(IContext context)
{
    var items = GetHttpContextItems();
    var session = default(ISession);
    var sessionExists = items.Contains(SessionKey);

    if (!sessionExists)
    {
        session = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>(Name).OpenSession();
        items.Add(SessionKey, session);
    }
    else
    {
        session = (ISession)items[SessionKey];
    }

    return session;
}

// a Func which serves access to the HttpContext.Current.Items collection
private Func<IDictionary> GetHttpContextItems { get; set; }
```

Please note that we use two sessions, one for ordinary domain de/hydration and one for CQRS, hence the pair of bindings in the Container.

Comment: THIS IS NOW RESOLVED (for the time being....)

Comment: We encounter same issues like yours on WCF applications. How did you resole it?

Answer (score 1):

The error messages indicate that you are not managing transactions correctly. I think the root cause is that you are handling transactions in the repository methods which in my opinion is a very poor design. Your repositories should have an ISession injected into their constructors, and your controllers should have any repositories they are dependent upon injected into their constructors. It's easy to wire this all up with Ninject. With this approach you can use transaction-per-request or (much better imo) manage the transaction in the action methods.

Here's how I'm setting up NHibernate with Ninject in NinjectWebCommon. The root cause of your problem may be that you are binding the ISession in request scope and storing it in HttpContext, which is unnecessary. I am also confused why you have two sets of bindings for Domain and Query.

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider(new SessionFactoryProvider()).InSingletonScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISession>().ToProvider(new SessionProvider()).InRequestScope();
    }

    private class SessionFactoryProvider : Provider<ISessionFactory>
    {
        protected override ISessionFactory CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
           // create and configure the session factory
           // I have a utility class to do this so the code isn't shown
           return nhibernateHelper.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
    }

    private class SessionProvider : Provider<ISession>
    {
        protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            var sessionFactory = context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>();
            var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
            return session;
        }
    }
```

A sample controller action using a transaction. Managing transactions outside of the repositories is important for several reasons:

- Allows multiple repositories to participate in a transaction
- Allows the controller to set the transaction boundaries (unit of work)
- Allows lazy loads to occur in the transaction
- Transactions are needed for read operations if second level caching is used. Even if it caching isn't used I think it's a best practice

  ```
  public ActionResult EditDocuments(int id, string name)
  {
      using (var txn = _session.BeginTransaction())
      {
          var summary = _characterizationRepository
              .GetCharacterization(id)
              .AsCharacterizationSummaryView()
              .ToFutureValue();

          var documents = _characterizationRepository
              .GetCharacterization(id)
              .SelectMany(c => c.Documents)
              .OrderBy(d => d.FileName)
              .AsDocumentSelectView(true)
              .ToFuture();

          if (summary.Value == null)
          {
              throw new NotFoundException(_characterizationRepository.ManualId, "Characterization", id);
          }

          CheckSlug(name, summary.Value.Title);

          var model = new DocumentSectionEditView()
              {
                  CharacterizationSummary = summary.Value,
                  Documents = documents.ToArray()
              };

          txn.Commit();
          return View(model);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't understand your commentary, I'm afraid.  Since we are using an IoC Container, you can rightly expect that any repository has a session injected, and any controller or web-form codebehind has a repository injected.  However, this has no bearing on how transactions are managed, at least not without a lot more explanation.  If transactions are not managed within the repository CRUD methods, where should they be managed?  I have updated my question further to provide more of our code.

Comment: Transactions should be managed in the controller actions. Your design makes it impossible to call more than one repository method in the same transaction. I will post mine NH configuration code for comparison.

Comment: Your Binding code for ISession and SessionFactory is functionally indistinguishable from ours, which is encouraging.  Please could you post a sample action method which uses your approach, so that we can see how you manage transactions in your application layer.  Thanks.

Comment: Will do. The fundamental difference I see is that you are instructing Ninject to construct the ISession in request scope but at the same time you are providing a method that stores the ISession in HttpContext.

Comment: I take your point concerning the arrangement of transactions, and clearly the widespread use of a generic repository coupled with the use of transactions within its methods leads to the situation you describe - operations cannot be grouped into units of work which need to have a consistent atomic state.  As a matter of interest, though, how do you justify the pollution of your application layer with concerns from the layer below (or even below that - since an ISession is a very low-level class), and the hard-coupling of your application layer to your ORM implementation?

Comment: The full answer is a much longer discussion than I am willing to type and "pollution" is pejorative but here goes. My technical justification is that the ISession represents a unit-of-work and a query engine and it is appropriate (I would argue necessary) to expose it to the application. My business justification is that doing so streamlines the application and makes developers more productive. I have a lot of good company in this position, this is a common and recommended approach. I think you have the question backwards: it's complexity and dogmatic architecture that must be justified.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271265/correct-use-of-the-nhibernate-unit-of-work-pattern-and-ninject and http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/09/20/limiting-your-abstractions/.

Comment: As you say, not the forum for this kind of commentary/discussion.  Had I sufficient privileges, I would give you +2 for insight into problematic use of transactions within repository methods.

Comment: Also, while one can argue that the ISession and Nhibernate's transaction are library specific implementations, the wider _concept_ of transactions are something generic which can be more visible in your application. On the other, putting transactions in some top-level request routing/action filter/interceptor, you would have only a one or a couple of classes that knows specifically about NHibernate transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong context manager, check if you are using the WebSessionContext. This context manager will bind your session to the httpcontext of the current call instead of the thread. What happens now under load (the spider), when you are using the ThreadStaticSessionContext, session will 'jump' to an other 'call'.

Comment: Adding this line    config.CurrentSessionContext<WebSessionContext>();    makes no difference whatever.  We still see exactly the same results.  Will add session factory code to ticket

Comment: Check if you are handling calls in a WCF context and if there is a HTTPContext in those calls. If not, the WebSessionContext will not work for those calls and you need the WCFSessionContext of enable the HTTPContext in your web.config.

Comment: This is an ASP.Net app - we are not using WCF.